# Fetch : status 302 in Edge 17

Tags: json, microsoft-edge, fetch-api, http-status-code-302

I'm using js fetch API to retreive datas from JSON.
It's working fine (even in IE 11), except in Edge 17 i get 302, the response header are :

- Content-length : 0
- Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
- Location: http://local.mysite.com/xxx

My local website is on a Mac, i'm using BrowserSync to make it reachable via 192.168.100.X:3000
Then i've updated my PC hosts file like this :

```
192.168.100.X  http://local.mysite.com
```

Here's my fetch call :

```
   fetch('/fr/fil-actualites-json', { mode: 'cors' })
      .then(
        function(response) {
          console.log('code :' +response.status);
          if (response.status !== 200) {
            console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
              response.status);
            return;
          }

          // Examine the text in the response
          response.json().then(function(data) {
            // do some stuff
          });
        }
      )
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
      });
```

Thx for your help ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Safari was throwing this error :

```
unhandled promise rejection syntaxerror the string did not match the expected pattern
```

I found [the answer](https://github.com/github/fetch/tree/3674c98df696d45573750aa7873814887d25689a#sending-cookies):

> The default value for credentials is "same-origin".
>
> The default for credentials wasn't always the same, though. The
>   following versions of browsers implemented an older version of the
>   fetch specification where the default was "omit":
>
> Firefox 39-60 Chrome 42-67 Safari 10.1-11.1.2 If you target these
>   browsers, it's advisable to always specify credentials: 'same-origin'
>   explicitly with all fetch requests instead of relying on the default:

```
fetch('/users', {
  credentials: 'same-origin'
})
```